# Why is my dog afraid of flies?

Tags: dogs, behavior

For some odd reason, my Schipperke mix is extremely afraid of flies. Whenever he hears or sees a fly, he runs and hides. He isn't really afraid of them outside though. He has even learned the word "fly". My question is, why is he so afraid of them and how can I help him?

Comment: has your dog been earlier bitten by flies?

Comment: Is this a recent behaviour or has he always had it? How long have you had the dog, how old is he, and when is the first time you noticed this behaviour?

Comment: I don't know if he has been bitten in general by flies, but usually the flies here are just regular house flies. He has had this behavior for as long as we have had him. We got him from the local shelter about three years ago, he is eight years old and I don't really remember the first time I noticed this behavior.

Comment: Being a shelter pet there is no telling.  It may be that he was kept in a small box that was swarmed with flies as punishment and the fly sounds bring it back.  There is no real way to answer this question though.  Anything we could give you is just a guess and probably is not going to help you.  You might be better off asking how you can help your dog get over his fear.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it needs more detail about the pet's background. When did this first start, rescue pet?, any particular bad experiences.

Comment: When a fly is around do you loudly and quickly try to smash it? It might be that the dog learned that the noise of a fly means you are about to make a loud noise.